# USB device detection using actionscript 3 from flash

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, usb, flash-cs4

Is it possible to detect usb device using actionscript 3 from flash cs4?
Pls. let me know.

Thanks & Regards,
Sagar

Answer (score 0):

Is your Flash movie running in the browser (is it a remote SWF) or an AIR application?

Either way, the simple answer is no. In case of an AIR application, you might be able to use the [NativeProcess](http://mchristoff.com/2009/12/using-the-air-2-0-nativeprocess-api-to-control-mplayer/) API to start a C/Java demon application that does the monitoring for your AIR application.