# Can flash actionscript detect which device is typing?

Tags: jquery, actionscript-3, flash, web-applications, barcode-scanner

im building myself a little web app database for my shop that tracks my stock and staff via a barcode scanner.

i've done all the work but am now having a problem with the scanner input box not having focus after i've been using the DB to search figures etc.

I have some precautions like `$('#Barcode_box').focus();` after clicking anything not needing interaction (ie not an input box) & a timer that is started if the mouse is inactive for so many mins/seconds (not ideal). But this is still not failsafe!

i know flash on a webpage can access webcam and mic and i know how to call javascript functions or have java-s call its functions from a webpage.

But i was wondering as the barcode scanner effectively types and returns (ascii 13) **is there actually any way to detect what device is typing or sending a signal to the client machine?**

i have tried googling lots of different things, even for any as3 code that can directly listen to the com port of the Bcode scanner for input and directly post to box, but to no avail.

any help is muchly appreciated. i am thinking maybe of having a flash keystroke listener, but feel this would probably be a bit heavy.

oh and this is on an internal network running wamp.

i did come across this also [USB device detection using actionscript 3 from flash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387397/usb-device-detection-using-actionscript-3-from-flash)

Comment: chrome and opera seem to fire `window.onpaste` when i paste. i do have focus on the browser window, but not any form element. maybe you can look at the event target element to see if the paste is targeted at a user field. edit- i assume the barcode scanner pastes the data.

Comment: It sounds like text being entered by your barcode scanner is really no different than you or I typing in the field. That is my long way of saying don't worry about who is inputing the text, and try to figure out why you are having issues w/focus. Do the same problems w/focus occur if you manually input the data? If not, can you explain what is different between the two scenarios? Aside from being somewhat jenky, what are the issues with your current work arounds?

Comment: thanks for the comments, the difference between me typing and the barcode typing is that if im at the computer and the input box doesnt have focus i would click in the box to focus and start typing where as the scanner just types wherever the focus is. so if for example i am adding a new employee to the database and am typing their name when another employee scans in the building it would type this in that box not the barcode one. if flash could know what device is typing it could call js func to focus on the box if it is the scanner sending the signal! my workarounds arent really failsafe.

Comment: i have found something about gamerinput on adobes site where flash/air can find and determine input devices like joysticks and controllers! this may be of some help to me, but it did mention something about TV's??? i will look into it further.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution i could come up with for now is a jquery one:

```
$("body").click(function(e) {
if($('input:not(#Barcode)').is(":focus")){}
else{
$('#Barcode').focus();}
```

});

seems to work ok after a couple of minutes testing....

EDIT:
Just incase any one has come accross this from a g search the code is saying: when the user clicks on anything -> if it is not focused on an input set focus to the barcode entry.

i may try a keypress listener aswell, just to be double sure!